# How can I make the stock browser stop asking which browser I want to use?

Tags: default-applications, stock-browser

I have a number of browsers installed on my phone.  I haven't set any as the default because some pages simply render better on some browsers than on others.

When I use the stock browser, *every single time* I click a link it asks me what browser I want to use.  I'd like it to get the hint that if I chose the stock browser for this current session, then it should open the links in the stock browser and stop asking me.

Is there any way for me to stop the stock browser from asking me this without making it the default?

Comment: This occurs to me only when there are redirects in the webpage and not "every time I click a link"

Answer (score 8):

No. Android works with intents. Opening a link is asking for an intent to open an url. If you have more than 1 browser and you haven't set a default, Android will ask you which one to choose.

I can imagine certain browsers not following this rule of starting an intent and just stay in their own program but that's all as the program decide to handle it.

Comment: @GAThrawn: Thanks for correcting the typos. Entering answers on an aPad is not necessarily the easiest thing to do.

Comment: This is definitely a design flaw

Answer (score 3):

The default Android behavior has no option for this. Like you mentioned you'll always get the question on each start of a browser intent (that is asking android to open an url in a browser). The only way to stop this is to select one and set it as a default.

On the other hand, once you're in a browser session the programmer of the browser could implement the request of a given url to be handled by itself, rather than starting a new browser intent. That would overcome your issue.

If you then start a browser intent to view a url you'll get the android option to select a browser. And the next urls will just be opened in the same browser. In other words it really depends on the implementation of that browser.